# NestJS : passport authenticate undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, linkedin-api, nestjs

I am using this [package](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2) with NestJs for passport LinkedIn login

as nestjs uses '@nestjs/passport' on top 'passport'

I have tried it with :

```
import { passport } from 'passport';
```

and passed it to the constructor so that I can use it e.g `this.passport`.

The documentation says that use it like :

```
app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```

My code :

```
  @Get('auth/linkedin/callback')
  linkedinCallBack() {
    this.passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login'
    }
  }
```

`this.passport.authenticate` always undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just create a strategy and use the `AuthGuard()` [like the docs show](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)